# How can I print 10 lines above and until a matching word below for each matching line?

Tags: parsing, sed, terminal, grep

I need to parse log file so I output the errors(with the stack trace below), and 10 lines above each error.

For example:

**2017-10-29 00:00:10,440 INFO ...

2017-10-29 00:00:10,473 WARN ...

2017-10-29 00:00:10,504 INFO ...

2017-10-29 00:00:10,547 INFO ...

2017-10-29 00:00:10,610 INFO ...

2017-10-29 00:00:11,176 WARN ...

2017-10-29 00:00:11,894 WARN ..

2017-10-29 00:00:11,900 INFO ...

2017-10-29 00:00:11,900 INFO ...

2017-10-29 00:00:12,632 WARN ...

2017-10-29 00:00:12,946 ERROR...

...(stack trace)...

...(stack trace)...

...(stack trace)...**
2017-10-29 00:00:12,946 WARN

I need to output 10 lines above the ERROR until the the date(2017-10-29) below(not including the line of the date)

Thought about doing it with grep -n -B10 "ERROR"(for the 10 lines above) and sed '/ERROR/,/29/p'(for the stack trace) but how do I combine the two?

Comment: I can't think of a way of combining them, but it would be relatively straightforward to write a bash script to do this as a stand-alone task, without using either grep or sed.

Answer (score 1):

With **`grep`** + **`head`** pipeline:

```
grep -B10 'ERROR' g1 | head -n -1
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , Will it work if I have many ERRORs on the log file? I think head will only trim the last line on the piped data..Am I mistaken?

Comment: @RuthieZ, you did not mention that you *have many ERRORs on the log file*

Comment: This `grep | head` does not print the stack trace lines, regardless the number of errors in file. Question is for both, last ten lines and the error stack trace to be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;N;/ERROR/bb;s/[^\n]\+/&/11;Ta;D;:b;p;n;/2017-10-29$/!bb' file
```

Gather up at most 10 lines in the pattern space then use these lines as moving window through the file. When the string `ERROR` is encountered print the window and then any further lines until (but not including) the string `2017-10-29` is matched. Repeat if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way using awk:

```
awk '                     {a[++b]=$0}
     /^([0-9]{2,4}-?){3}/ {f=0}
     /ERROR/              {f=1; for(i=NR-10;i<NR;i++) print a[i]}
     f' file
```

we store each line to array. When matching a date log line, we unset the flag. When matching ERROR we set the flag and we print last 10 lines of the array. And when flag is on, we print (default action so we wrote just `f`)

This should print expected lines for all existing ERRORs in file.

note: the date regexp used is not strict but seems enough for the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
grep -no -B10 ' [0-9:,]* ERROR.*' infile
```

Need perhaps to substitute ' ' by [[:blank:]]